# Change the default ethernet card

Tags: networking, ethernet

I've a Ubuntu Server 14.04 and 2 ethernet card.

I now use only the eth1 and so I want to change my configuration because I cannot now access internet with my server.

I've change the file  /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The primary network interface for Internet
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.254
        network 192.168.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 109.88.203.3,62.197.111.140

# The secondary network interface for local network
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.201
network 192.168.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
```

I've also change the file  /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf and add the line :

```
supersede routers 192.168.1.1
```

If I run

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

It works

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=43 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=43 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=43 time=18.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=43 time=21.9 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.238/19.803/21.928/1.523 ms
```

But when i run sudo apt-get update it doesn't works :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'ppa.launchpad.net:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

What can I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's ok,

I've changed the file /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The primary network interface for Internet
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Now it's Ok